# HTTP Status Code 404 Java/Servlets

Tags: java, http, servlets, tomcat7, http-status-code-404

Even though I found several similar questions I'm not able to create my first `Hello World` Servlet.  I keep receiving status code 404.

So in the following folder `/home/smihai/apache-tomcat-7.0.52/webapps/HelloWorld/WEB-INF/` I have a **web.xml** file and another folder "classes" with 2 files: **HelloWorld.java** and **HelloWorld.class**.

The web.xml file contains:

```
<web-app>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>HelloWorld</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>HelloWorld</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>HelloWorld</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/HelloWorld</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

The HelloWorld.java contains:

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

public class HelloWorld extends HttpServlet{ 
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
                                   throws ServletException,IOException{
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter pw = response.getWriter();
        pw.println("<html>");
        pw.println("<head><title>Hello World</title></title>");
        pw.println("<body>");
        pw.println("<h1>Hello World</h1>");
        pw.println("</body></html>");
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What request do you send that results in a 404?

Comment: http://localhost:8080/HelloWorld/

Comment: Is your `HelloWorld` class in the default package or somewhere else?

Comment: Looks ok. Try moving your `HelloWorld` into a package. Maybe it will help?

Comment: did you try <url-pattern>HelloWorld</url-pattern> ?

Comment: I tried now ben, same error

Comment: Wouldn't this deploy to http://localhost:8080/HelloWorld/HelloWorld ?

Comment: thanks Geoff that was it.

Comment: Geoff send an answer (instead of a comment) so I cand accept it

Answer (score 0):

- You would need to put/move your `HelloWorld.java` class inside a package.
- URL would be: `localhost:8080/HelloWorld/HelloWorld`

### Folder Structure:

[image]

### HelloWorld.java:

```
package servlets;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class HelloWorld
 */
public class HelloWorld extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * Default constructor. 
     */
    public HelloWorld() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter pw = response.getWriter();
        pw.println("<html>");
        pw.println("<head><title>Hello World</title></title>");
        pw.println("<body>");
        pw.println("<h1>Hello World</h1>");
        pw.println("</body></html>");
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

}
```

### Servlet-Mapping:

```
<servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>HelloWorld</display-name>
    <servlet-name>HelloWorld</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>servlets.HelloWorld</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>HelloWorld</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/HelloWorld</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

### URL:

[image]